# div inside div inside <a href> css class

Tags: html, css, href

I'm using DevExpress components.
There are examples in the form of a div div.

```
<div id="ctl09_DvUrunler_EPContainer" class="dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aspxDVEPClick('ctl09_DvUrunler')"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I must do

```
<a style="width:100px; etc.." href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aspxDVEPClick('ctl09_DvUrunler')"></a>
```

but i can't write class for `<a href>` or inside div.

i think i should do

`.dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue > .div > .a {
    width: 760px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    font:16px !important;
}`

something like that. but it's not working. please help me.

Comment: remove the dots before the name of the tag in the css rule `.dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue > div > a`. dots are for classes

Comment: thank you for care, but I try this. not work

Comment: Well you may have other issues causing this not to work as expected, but the selector given by Hacketo is correct. That said you might aswell remove the `>` which targets direct children and in your example this is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the dots and add a `display:inline-block`

```
.dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue > div > a {
    width: 760px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

the `inline-block` allow you to set a size for an inline element.
Also `font` property does not exist, replace it with `font-size`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector should be

```css
.dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue > div > a
```

The difference is div instead of .div and a instead of .a

Answer (score 0):

Dor before element means it is a class, when you want to get element like div, just remove the dot.

```
.dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue > div > a {
    width: 760px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    font:16px !important;
}
```

This path will find:

- element with class dxdvEPContainer_MetropolisBlue
- div as direct child
- a as direct child of above div

Legend:

- div - element div
- .div - element with class="div"
- #div - element with id="div"

Answer (score 0):

add below css

```
#ctl09_DvUrunler_EPContainer div a{ 
 width: 760px !important; 
 height:40px !important; font:16px 
 !important;
}
```